# Unity-Photon Voice-Serialization Weaver Build error

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to add Photon Voice to my Unity app for Windows 10, but I'm getting an error when I try to build the app from Visual Studio.

```
System.Exception: Exception while processing UnityVoiceFrontend UnityVoiceFrontend PhotonVoiceNetwork::client, error Failed to resolve assembly: 'Assembly-CSharp-firstpass, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Unity.Serialization.Weaver.MethodEmitterBase.WillUnitySerialize(FieldDefinition fieldDefinition)
   at Unity.Serialization.Weaver.SerializeMethodEmitterBase.ShouldProcess(FieldDefinition fieldDefinition)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<CombinePredicates>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Unity.Serialization.Weaver.MethodEmitterBase.EmitMethodBody()
   at Unity.Serialization.Weaver.MethodEmitterBase.CreateMethodDef(String methodName)
   at Unity.Serialization.Weaver.SerializeMethodEmitter.SerializeMethodDefinitionFor(TypeDefinition typeDef, SerializationBridgeProvider serializationBridgeProvider)
   at Unity.Serialization.Weaver.SerializationWeaver.AddSerializeMethod()
   at Unity.Serialization.Weaver.SerializationWeaver.Weave()
   at usw.Weaver.WeaveAssembly(String assemblyPath, AssemblyDefinition unityEngineAssemblyDefinition, ReaderParameters readerParameters)
   at usw.Weaver.Weave()
   at usw.Program.RunProgram(ConversionOptions options)
   at usw.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Am I missing something or did I not do the set up correctly?
I followed the instructions [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/voice/current/getting-started/voice-for-pun)

Comment: This could be the same Unity issue as reported in http://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/30926/#Comment_30926

Comment: @photonians yeah that's me over there too. I sent a bug report to Unity and they were able to reproduce it so it might be their issue.